# Nodejs Express: Error when sending image from Postman to Multer

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, postman, multer

I have this route:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');

const upload = multer();

module.exports = (function () {

    var router = express.Router();

    router.post('/avatar/:user', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
        var file = req.file; // file passed from client
        var meta = req.body; // all other values passed from the client, like name, etc..
        console.log(file);
        console.log(meta);
        res.json({
            success: true
        });
    });

    return router;
})();
```

And when I try to post to it using Postman with header 'Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and in body 'form-data' File (image), the express crashes with error:

```
Error
    at readStream (F:\Web\WorkoutFocus_Server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:196
:17)
    at getRawBody (F:\Web\WorkoutFocus_Server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:106
:12)
    at read (F:\Web\WorkoutFocus_Server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:76:
3)
    at urlencodedParser (F:\Web\WorkoutFocus_Server\node_modules\body-parser\lib
\types\urlencoded.js:115:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\Web\WorkoutFocus_Server\node_modules
\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (F:\Web\WorkoutFocus_Server\node_modules\express\lib\router\i
ndex.js:317:13)
    at F:\Web\WorkoutFocus_Server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7

    at Function.process_params (F:\Web\WorkoutFocus_Server\node_modules\express\
lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (F:\Web\WorkoutFocus_Server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js
:275:10)
    at jsonParser (F:\Web\WorkoutFocus_Server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types
\json.js:112:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\Web\WorkoutFocus_Server\node_modules
\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (F:\Web\WorkoutFocus_Server\node_modules\express\lib\router\i
ndex.js:317:13)
    at F:\Web\WorkoutFocus_Server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7

    at Function.process_params (F:\Web\WorkoutFocus_Server\node_modules\express\
lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (F:\Web\WorkoutFocus_Server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js
:275:10)
    at cors (F:\Web\WorkoutFocus_Server\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:185:7)
```

Does this have something to do with file size or multipart/form-data perhaps?

I tried to set the bodyparser.json limit to '50mb', but no difference.

Comment: Why are you trying to post binary data via application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of multipart/form-data?

Comment: I dont really know how this works. From postman when i changed the 'Content-type : multipart/form-data' it gives error: Error: Multipart: Boundary not found. When i set the 'Content-type' to empty it goes trough but says file is undefined :/

Comment: You should not explicitly set/override the `Content-Type` header. Just select the 'form-data' radio button in Postman in the 'Body' tab.